# MySQL JOIN returning only 1 row out of several rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: questions and answers

It's relational, so the answers has a column called `question` which corresponds directly to the row in the `questions` column. I have the following query:

```
SELECT questions.id,
       questions.question,
       questions.author,
       questions.date,
       answers.answer,
       answers.user,
       answers.datetime
FROM questions
INNER JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.question
WHERE tag IN (:arrayIDs)
```

There are 3 questions, but only one answer that matches a question.

However, this MySQL string is only returning one question instead of all the questions.

How would I retrieve all the matching questions (which would come if I do simple `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause, which would still return more than 1 question) as well as the answer?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, LEFT JOIN will get you all Questions without an Answer:

```
SELECT questions.id,
       questions.question,
       questions.author,
       questions.date,
       answers.answer,
       answers.user,
       answers.datetime
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.question
WHERE tag IN (:arrayIDs)
```

Take a look at [SQL JOINs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKS1u.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You are using an INNER JOIN, which will only give you records for which the Question record is able to join to an Answer record. Change this to a LEFT OUTER JOIN and you should get the results I think you are expecting. A LEFT OUTER JOIN will always give you all records in the first table - plus the records in the second table, where possible.

Comment: Thank You. I'll do some more research on those two things.